# Can't find the latex code for the ⍎ (down tack jot) symbol

Tags: symbols, unicode

I'm new to LaTeX and I don't know how to use the [CTAN package](https://ctan.org/pkg/apl) for typing APL symbols. So far I use the `wasysym` package but symbols like the ⍎ (down tack jot) are not included.

I have downloaded the `apl` CTAN package which is a directory of various files but I can't find instructions on how to use it in my LaTeX editor (TeXworks).

Please can you tell me how to use this package?

Comment: which tex distro do you have? miktex or texlive? If you have miktex, better install it with the miktex console because installing font things manually is really tricky.

Comment: I use TeXworks as my LaTeX editor

Comment: Your editor does not matter. The tex distribution would be interesting to know. miktex? telive? mactex? something exotic? Does any of these names ring a bell?

Comment: I currently use pdfLaTeX - does that sound right?

Comment: no, this is an engine. I would need to know the name of the distribution that provides pdflatex for you. Can you search your computer for `miktex`, `telive` and `mactex` and see if any of this brings up some hits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can superimpose `\perp` and `\circ`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\APLdtj}{%
  \begingroup\m@th
  \vphantom{$\perp$}%
  \ooalign{\hfil\raisebox{0.2ex}{$\circ$}\hfil\cr$\perp$\cr}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\APLbox \quad \APLdtj \quad \APLcomment

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\dtjot{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{\dimexpr.6\LMpt+.2pt\relax}%
  {\SavedStyle\perp}{\SavedStyle\kern-.2pt\kern.08pt\circ}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}
}
\begin{document}
$\dtjot\quad\scriptstyle\dtjot\quad\scriptscriptstyle\dtjot$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the circle smaller,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,graphicx}
\newcommand\dtjot{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{\dimexpr1\LMpt+.2pt\relax}%
  {\SavedStyle\perp}{\scalebox{.7}{$\SavedStyle\kern-.18pt\kern.08pt\circ$}}%
  {O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}
}
\begin{document}
$\dtjot\quad\scriptstyle\dtjot\quad\scriptscriptstyle\dtjot$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow - stackengine and scalerel are not found using my TeXworks editor ...I'll check what distro I'm using. @user185220

Comment: @awyr_agored You can always get the style files here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine and https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scalerel

Answer (score 5):

As you just used the Unicode symbol ⍎, you’re aware of it.  You can use that in LaTeX, too.  Load the `fontspec` package, compile in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, and you can paste it into your source code.  `^^^^234E` also works, as does `\char{"234e}`, or you can define a `\newcommand`.

If your main font doesn’t contain that glyph, you can define the command in text mode like so:

```
\newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Sans}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\newcommand\dtjot{{\symbolfont ⍎}}
```

In math mode, you would load `unicode-math` and use the `range=` option of `\setmathfont` if the main math font you want to use does not cover it.  You could also put the text-mode command inside a `\mbox`.